# Splitting a string using regex

Tags: php, regex

I would like to split a string where any character is a space or punctuation (excluding apostrophes). The following regex works as intended.

```
/[^a-z']/i
```

Words like I'll and Didn't are accepted, which is great.

The problem is with words like 'ere and 'im. I would like to remove the beginning apostrophe and have the words im and ere.

I would ideally like to stop/remove this within the regex pattern if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what programming language?

Comment: PHP, using the preg_split function

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to do this with just a regex.

Comment: This really sounds like a job for decomposition; first create the array, then replace the words starting with the apostrophe with words where it has been stripped. Much easier on the eyes than adding exceptions to the regexp until it is unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$str = "Words like I'll and Didn't are accepted, which is great. 
        The problem is with words like 'ere and 'im";
print_r(preg_split("/'?[^a-z']+'?/i", $str));
//Array ( [0] => Words [1] => like [2] => I'll [3] => and [4] => Didn't ... 
//        [16] => ere [17] => and [18] => im )
```

Comment: Worked great, thanks! Quick question, I thought the question mark meant optional in regex? How does that work?

Comment: @Ben, question mark means "1 or 0 times". So if there is an apostrophe to the left (that would match ' as in "Dickens' Novels") or to the right  (matches ' as in "like 'ere") of the [^a-z']+ it will be captured by the pattern.